# Search using a regular expression with alternation

Tags: search, grep, regex

I'd like to search files containing `G Bush`, `J Bush`, `B Bush`, or `H Bush`.

The following command can achieve the goal:

```
grep -rnE "G Bush|J Bush|B Bush|H Bush"
```

Can we do something like the following so that we can save some keystrokes?

```
grep -rnE "{G|J|B|H} Bush"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [a bracket expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05):

```
grep -rn "[GJBH] Bush"
```

Or group your or-expressions:

```
grep -rnE "(G|H|J|B) Bush"
```

Comment: You again, thats not fair ;)

Comment: Or if the amount of patterns is large, put things into a file and use `-f` flag